# Check if directory exist, if so continue, if not die

Tags: php

Have trolled many questions here and have not been able to find solution, so...

We create PHP exercises for kids to learn from. Sometimes they have to create folders which may remain empty until many steps later. If the kids skip creating folder, then PHP throws nasty error. Like to show custom error using code something like this:

```
$file = 'mydir';
if(is_dir($file)) {
  die("<p>folder does not exist, please return and create as instructed...</p>");
} else {
  $file=fopen($file,"r");
}
```

So to recap. Function checks if directory exist, if it does the script continues, it not dies and shows simple message until directory is created. **I do not wish for PHP to create directory if it does not exist**, the kids must learn to follow steps:)

My code will not continue even though directory exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `if` condition is upside-down :) Don't throw away some up-votes to some quick me too me too answers while you get some down-votes. You just have to look at the code itself to find the problem. That code is dying when the directory exists and continuing when it does not

Comment: Crap, I knew should have slept on this one... Been a long day. Thanks for getting me back on track.

Answer (score 0):

You have put in the wrong condition:
Below is the correct condition.

```
$file = 'mydir';
if(is_dir($file))
{
    //DIRECTORY EXISTS
}
else
{
    //DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST
}
```

Comment: With fear of my edit getting rejected (Stack Overflow is unpredictable), I suggest you replace the current text with "You have gotten the code blocks the wrong way round. Swap them around like so:".

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Use single quotes when double quotes aren't necessary, it will treat the contents as is (that is it doesn't affect it), which is simpler as you don't have to use "\" for control characters (with the exception of "\'" if you want single quotes in your string) and it makes your code more efficient as PHP doesn't have to check for escape characters.

```
$location = 'mydir'; //Better call it location as directory =/= file.

if(is_dir($location))
{
    //$fout = fopen($file, 'rb'); //'rb' for binary mode, please use this instead.
    $fout = fopen($location . '/' . $file, 'rb'); //I assumed you wanted to write the file in the directory you were testing for.
}
else
{
    die('<p>folder does not exist, please return and create as instructed...</p>');
}
```

Comment: @Woody Strange. Anyway, when you think you've got the best answer, be sure to click the green tick.